# wrap range of <li> items within a div container

Tags: jquery, html, css

Suppose I've the following DOM tree:

```
<div id="parent-container">
 <ul>
  <li>item-1</li>
  <li>item-2</li>
  <li>item-3</li>
  <li>item-4</li>
  <li>item-5</li>
  ...
 </ul>
</div>
```

How do I wrap all items from item-3 to n items in a `div` or in another `ul` or any element that I can use to impose a vertical scrollbar on the container that hold items from item-3 onward.

Desired output should be:

```
<div id="parent-container">
 <ul>
  <li>item-1</li>
  <li>item-2</li>
  <div id="child-container">
   <li>item-3</li>
   <li>item-4</li>
   <li>item-5</li>
   ...
   </div>
 </ul>
</div>
```

I tried the following and had no luck:

`$('#parent-container ul *:nth-child(n+3)').wrapInner('<div class="child-container"></div>');`

Comment: use `.wrapAll('<div class="child-container"></div>'); `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery `:gt() selector` then `.wrapAll() method.`

```
$('#parent-container li:gt(3)').wrapAll('<div id="child-container"></div>'))
```

See [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to itsgoingdown answer: you could use slice() if you need to wrap a range of elements up to a specified n:

```
var i = 2;
var n = 4;
$("#parent-container ul li").slice(i, n).wrapAll("<div class='child-container'></div>");
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/macro64/pen/EKNQwb)